# SQL split entries in table into 2 columns based on entries in second columns

Tags: sql, mariadb

I need to write an sql query for a database to get some values for a react table.

I have 2 tables that look something like this:

| group_id | task_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1234 |
| 2 | 3456 |
| 2 | 5555 |
| 3 | 3333 |

| task_id | assigned id | name | value | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 264545 | item1 | 1000 | 1 |
| 3456 | ssdfsd | item2 | 2000 | 1 |
| 5555 | wedadw | item3 |  | 2 |
| 3333 | 23eder | item4 |  | 2 |
| 4444 | bingbong | item5 | 999 | 1 |

task_id in both columns are the same and type 2 doesnt have any 'value'.

I want a result where rows in the second table are split into 2 sets of columns based on the 'type' value but rows with matching 'group_id' from the first table are on same row, so in this example it would look like this:

| group_id | type1id | type1name | type2id | type2name | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 264545 | item1 |  |  | 1000 |
| 2 | ssdfsd | item2 | wedadw | item3 | 2000 |
| 3 |  |  | 23eder | item4 |  |
|  | bingbong | item5 |  |  | 999 |

Some entries like 'bingbong' have no group_id but should still be shown on their own row. Does this make sense? I want to keep all the empty fields too.

I've tried a few queries but always seem to be missing something. (even chatgpt couldn't give me an answer)

The closest i got was this:

```
SELECT
t1.group_id,
MAX(CASE WHEN t2.type = 1 THEN t2.assigned_id END) AS type1id,
MAX(CASE WHEN t2.type = 1 THEN t2.name END) AS type1name,
MAX(CASE WHEN t2.type = 1 THEN t2.value END) AS value,
MAX(CASE WHEN t2.type = 2 THEN t2.assigned_id END) AS type2id,
MAX(CASE WHEN t2.type = 2 THEN t2.name END) AS type2name
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.task_id=t2.task_id
GROUP BY t1.group_id";
```

But it only gave me rows that had the matching group_id, but i need all the other rows too.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that it's possible to have multiple unmatched table2 rows that shouldn't be consolidated, I think you'd want to assign a unique id to keep them distinct during the aggregation process. Using negative numbers generated via `row_number()` is an easy way to accomplish that given that that range is probably unused:

```
with t2 as (
    select *, -1 * row_number() over (order by task_id) as surrogate_group
    from table2
)
select
    min(case when t1.group_id is not null then t1.group_id end) as group_id,
    min(case when t2.type = 1 then t2.assigned_id end) as type1id,
    min(case when t2.type = 1 then t2.name end) as type1name,
    min(case when t2.type = 2 then t2.assigned_id end) as type2id,
    min(case when t2.type = 2 then t2.name end) as type2name,
    min(case when t2.type = 1 then t2.value end) as value
from t2 left outer join table1 t1 on t1.task_id = t2.task_id
group by coalesce(t1.group_id, t2.surrogate_group)
order by
    min(case when t1.group_id is not null then 0 else 1 end),
    min(abs(surrogate_group));
```

Presumably that `order by` clause is only necessary to display the results in the order listed above and could be removed. I've included it just in case.

If that method seems messy then an alternative is to use a union. The first part, with an inner join, catches all the rows that do have task ids. The second half of the result then uses a left join filtered for the rows that failed to match. I've included an example in the linked fiddle. It's mostly a repetition of the same query yet it might also perform better than faking out the id numbers.

https://dbfiddle.uk/TDWIvvrf